# How to achieve Gigavolts?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, voltage

I was searching the internet when I found this article http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1764, about achieving high voltage and power to ignite thermonuclear reaction by inertial confinement, the plan was to achieve it in a ultra vacuum and something that have to do with "taylor flow " which includes quantum physics which I really dont know anything about.
So I searched more and all the sites ( including wikipedia ) where talking about maximum voltage related to gas surrounding, why can't we surround it with liquid with a much higher dielectric strength?

Comment: At some point, the electric field strength is going to be so high that electrons will be torn off of pretty much anything.

Comment: i didnt get what you just said